# How do I load the model artifact from AWS Sagemaker built-in container?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using the linear-learner container from Sagemaker to train a model. The training has completed and the model artifact is saved in S3. I download it which is a .tar.gz file and there is the actual model file stored in it called model-algo-1 without format extension. I'm trying to load this model and inspect the model coefficients but not sure how to do so.

I tried pickle and joblib but they didn't work. Does anyone know how to load the model file trained from Sagemaker built-in container? Or is there any other way I can check the model coefficients? It's a logistic regression model.

Thanks

Comment: A bit too late, but I was wondering if you found an answer for this

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working.

From the [SageMaker documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/v2.49.0/algorithms/linear_learner.html), there are two classes that can be used to load an already deployed Linear Learner

### Option 1: Use sagemaker.LinearLearnerModel to build predictor from S3 artificat

According to the documentation, this class:

> "Reference LinearLearner s3 model data"

You can use it as following:

##### Step 1: Build LinearLearner Model using the artificats hosted on S3

```
from sagemaker import LinearLearnerModel, get_execution_role, Session
import boto3
sess = boto3.Session(region_name=region_name)
sagemaker_session = Session(boto_session=sess)
role = get_execution_role(sagemaker_session)
model = LinearLearnerModel(model_data, role, sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)
```

##### Step 2: Deploy the model to an endpoint (in this example it is a serverless endpoint)

```
my_serverless_inference_config = ServerlessInferenceConfig(memory_size_in_mb=2048, max_concurrency=1)
linear_predictor = model .deploy(endpoint_name=my_endpoint_name,serverless_inference_config=my_serverless_inference_config,serializer=CSVSerializer(), deserializer=JSONDeserializer())
from sagemaker.predictor import csv_serializer, json_deserializer
linear_regressor.serializer = csv_serializer
linear_regressor.deserializer = json_deserializer
```

##### Step 3: use the sagemaker.predictor object returned by the deploy function

```
result = linear_predictor.predict(X_test)
#Iterate the result JSON to get an NP array of all the predictions so we can compare to Y test
predictions = np.array([res['score'] for res in result['predictions']])
```

### Option 2: Use LinearLearnerPredictor to build a predictor from an already endpoint

You can follow this option if your model has an already deployed endpoint

```
from sagemaker import LinearLearnerPredictor, get_execution_role, Session
import boto3
sess = boto3.Session(region_name=region_name)
sagemaker_session = Session(boto_session=sess)
role = get_execution_role(sagemaker_session)
predictor = LinearLearnerPredictor(endpoint_name, sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)
```